# how to update node on AWS for sudo

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sudo, nvm

I recently upgraded my node using nvm to the latest version 9.4.0.  I was getting all sorts of errors when running using sudo.  I realized the problem was the sudo was using a different version of node.

```
node -v
v9.4.0
sudo node -v
v0.10.48
```

I am using AWS-EC2 for my backend.

How can I update the sudo node to 9.4.0?  I tried running sudo nvm install 9.4.0 but I get sudo: nvm: command not found.  I'm new to node and not an expert in backend programming.